# What is the cost of Japanese visa for Ukrainians?

Tags: visas, japan, ukrainian-citizens

According to [the Ministry of Foreign Affairs](http://www.mofa.go.jp/j_info/visit/visa/procedure/fee.html):

> The fees are about 3,000 yen for a single-entry visa, 6,000 yen for a double-entry or multiple-entry visa, and 700 yen for a transit visa. Fees are collected in the currency of the country (region) in which the Embassy / Consulate General is located.
>
> Depending on the purpose of your visit and your nationality, fees may not be required or may be a different amount.

But there is zero information about the price on the local website.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**As long as you are Ukrainian and apply in Ukraine, it is free.**

According to [the Embassy of Japan in Ukraine website](http://www.ua.emb-japan.go.jp/jpn/consular/info/jpvisa.html):

> #### 4. 査証手数料について
>
> ウクライナ人の査証申請については無料です。他の国籍の方の査証申請手数料については，在外公館又は外務省にお問い合わせ下さい。

This reads as:

> #### 4. About the application fees
>
> It is free for Ukraines to apply for the visa. For citizens from other countries, contact the Embassy or a consulate, or the Ministry of Foreign Affairs.

Comment: By the way the *English* button on the top-right corner for some reasons lead to the Embassy of Japan in Moldova...